# Is there an up-to-date version of wso2 wsf for php?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, wso2, wsh

Is there a more up-to-date version of wso2's wsf framework for PHP? The [latest version on GitHub](https://github.com/wso2/wsf) doesn't seem to have an installation script, and the [tutorials](http://kkpradeeban.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/installing-wso2-wsfphp-on-ubuntu-1004.html) I've found for newer versions don't seem to work at all, despite seeming to have found the latest version (2.1.0?).

Even after finding the ./configure script it still won't make and install on our server (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: As far as i know, No..

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue. I downloaded an alternate tar.gz of the source code from here:
http://dist.wso2.org/products/wsf/php/2.1.0/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0.tar.gz

This does have the configure file (although I am getting compilation errors afterwards, but your environment might be different).

Answer (score 1):

for those that might be interested, i have begun a rewrite of this extension using php-cpp allowing to support php >= 5.6, this is a work in progress developpment.

[project here](https://github.com/alexis-gruet/kt_wso2-phpcpp-client)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install it successfully on Ubuntu 15.04

You have to install some required packages

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 libxml2 libxml2-dev php5-xsl php5-dev php5-config librampart-dev
```

then you have to download the source from http://dist.wso2.org/products/wsf/php/2.1.0/wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0.tar.gz, configure it with gcc 4.4

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
./configure CC=gcc-4.4
```

and then you can make and make install.

If you run into compiling errors check this guide https://jackson-brain.com/compiling-wso2-web-services-framework-for-php-5-5/